# R regression with categorical response variable

Tags: r, regression, classification, data-imputation

I have four variables, two are categorical and two are numeric:

```
a<-c("yes","yes","no","no","no",NA,"yes","no")
b<-c("high","low","medium","medium","medium","low",NA,NA)
c<-c(12,23,23,12,23,34,12,NA)
d<-c(1.2,1.3,4.5,3.4,NA,5.4,9.4,7.4)

df<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

I want to replace the `NA` values in each variable by using a model fit.
For example:

```
a~b+c+d; b~a+c+d
```

and so on.

I know that if all the variables are numeric, a simple multiple linear regression model can be built to estimate the value of the `NA` data.  However, I am not sure how I can achieve this if the response variable is categorical.

Comment: Logistic regression?

Comment: Do I have to recode the categories into numbers first?  Also,I thought logistic regression is only for 2 classes?

Comment: Read `?glm` documentation. And yes, you have only two classes in `a`

Comment: Oh, you also want `b` as DV, try `multinom` function in `nnet` package

Comment: I did read it and have tried out the examples but I am still not sure how to use the summary of the model to predict the missing value

Comment: See [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm) for example

Comment: Why do you want to predict the missing value? Prediction with categorical outcomes is a bit tricky as basically the prediction is the category that is most probable given the model parameters and the covariate values. The more difficult problem in your dataset is that also the covariates have missing values. `glm` will probably delete the cases with missing values. If you want to treat those, have a look at `mice` for example.

Comment: @Sineversighs Use `predict`, or roll your own by extracting the parameters with `coef`.

Comment: Basically, I have a much larger dataset (over 5000 rows and 50 variables) and some of the variables may be related to other variables, therefore I am trying to see if this model fit approach would give me a better dataset for further analysis.

Comment: @Sineversighs can you tell me where I can find an example?  I am struggling with finding an example that I can understand!  I am not a very experienced R user.

Comment: This is not really a specific programming problem. This is a statistical modeling problem. It wounds like you ware interested in some form of imputation for dealing with missing data. You should familiarize with yourself with missing data methods before trying to program a solution. It sounds you don't know how to do it anywhere and it's not R specific.

Comment: here is a readable intro to missing data imputation:  www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/missing.pdf.  from there, look into more complex articles on multiple imputation by Rubin

Answer (score 2):

> However, I am not sure how I can achieve this if the response variable
>   is categorical.

`b` has a cardinality of 3: [low, medium, high]. Try multinomial logistic regression. [Here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm) is an example from the experts.

**PS1:** Note that you can actually do this with any [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) algorithm, and do not need to limit yourself to multinomial logistic regression.

**PS2:** On the other hand, if you want to use a more "formal" solution for imputing missing data, you can use the [MICE](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) package by R.

**PS3:** Another methodology for imputing missing data is expectation maximization (EM), although I do not know of any R packages for this. I would suggest googling.

Comment: While expectation-maximization (EM) approach can be implemented manually (http://statistical-research.com/imputing-missing-data-with-expectation-maximization), it's probably a better idea to use a solid R package. For example, `Amelia` package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia) implements a variation of EM algorithm, combining EM with bootstrapping and naturally called EMB: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/vignettes/amelia.pdf.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh I was just about to post about `Amelia II`!

Comment: @user777: This world is so fast-paced... :-). For better or worse, being first doesn't always mean being better (implying myself).